# jquery ajax does not working when returning with php json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

**SOLVED**

problem solved, please see bottom answer for my solution

i've been struggling with this, i read tutorials about `$.ajax()`

here's the script

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#getData').click(
                function()
                {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        cache: false
                    });
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://localhost/Practice/Jquery/ajax/phone_data.php',
                        data: {rating: 5},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#display').html(data.phone);
                        },
                    error: function(response)
                    {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                    });//end ajax

                });//end click
        });//end ready
</script>

<body>
                <input type="button" id="getData" name="submitButton" value="getJson!" />

    <div id="display">
        replace me with phone data
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is the phone_data.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$data['phone'] = '989898989';
$data['username'] = 'sendyHalim';
echo json_encode($data, true);
exit();
```

when i click the button, firebug displays the request is OK, but nothing happens..

so i check the 'response' for the ajax call through firebug and get :

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost/Practice/Jquery/ajax/phone_data.php?rating=5&_=1368793325734
```

**Update**
i updated my code , i search some way around to get the response text(using `responseText` property from `response`), but it just alert with empty string(nothing).

here's the output when i run phone_data.php script alone:

```
{"phone":"989898989","username":"sendyHalim"}
```

and `"view page info"` from firefox confirms that the content-type is `"application/json"`

Comment: Stick an `error` callback function on your AJAX call and see what error jQuery is reporting.

Comment: You should be able to see the response in the console tab of Firebug without reloading.

Comment: and could you print the content you see in browser when you open the JSON fie?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i updated my code with function to display error, but it displays nothing..
@JayBlanchard from console tab, there's no response in the console tab(response section)
@imsiso i can't anyway its not json file, before im doing this (script above) i've been using `$.get` and when i display the json response, it displays undefined(with the same php script)

Comment: BTW you don't need `header('Content-type: application/json');` and add `exit()`; at the end after `echo json_encode..` and try

Comment: try changing `echo json_encode($data);` to `die(json_encode($data));` - this will ensure no trailing characters.

Comment: Replace `alert(response.responseText);` with `console.log(response);` and check the error in your JS console (F12)

Comment: please just print on bottom of your question content of page 'http://localhost/Practice/Jquery/ajax/phone_data.php' when you open it in browser.

Comment: Or, better yet, actually use the correct parameters. `error: function(jqXhr, statusText, errorThrown) {console.log(statusText + ': ' + errorThrown);}`

Comment: erm i updated it still no response, but when im using the script from @vincent (2nd answer below) it works(with his url) but when i change the url to my url (URI phone_data.php) it doesnt, i think the problem is with my php script? anyway i updated my php script

Answer (score 1):

I copy-pasted your code and replaced the url for the json request.

Take a look at the JSON URL. http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two

And the jQuery code that I modified a bit for the html output.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#getData').click(function () {
        
        var jsonUrl = 'http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two';
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: jsonUrl,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#display').html(data.one + ' and ' + data.key);
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                $('#display').html('error fetching data');
            }
        }); //end ajax
    }); //end click
}); //end ready
```

Here is your code :
http://jsfiddle.net/wuaNC/

Comment: And don't forget to parse your PHP Array properly. Modify your json_encode($data) to "json_encode($data,true)".

Comment: hi im using your code and it displays correctly using the url, but when i change url to my url : `http://localhost/Practice/Jquery/ajax/phone_data.php` it doesnt display anything(response is empty), i edited my php script in the thread above

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Guys it's my mistake LOL! Just for education, if you have the same problem as me (script is correct etc etc)... The problem is that I'm opening `display_json.html` from a local file. This means I right click the file then open with firefox. When I open it through localhost/pathToYourScript, however, it will run.

One thing I don't get is that if I open it from a local file using a url that pointing to another domain (like the one in the vincent's answer) it works, but when I use my local url, it doesn't.

Thanks for the tips and answers, you guys really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to global your scripts for UTF-8?